# MongoDB: Copy a collection of referenced documents as subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongohq

I made the mistake of designing a scheme so that I have two collections where one has documents which contain a manual reference to the other. I realized now that I should have created it so that the parent collection contained the other collection as sub-documents instead.

The problem is, I've already put this scheme out into a production environment where hundreds of entries have already been created. What I'd like to do is somehow scan over all of the existing data, and copy the items to their referenced parent_id as a sub-document.

Here is an example of my schema:

**Collection 1 - User**

```
_id
Name
```

**Collection 2 - Photos**

```
_id
url
user_id
```

Is there a quick way to change the existing documents to be one collection like this:

**Collection - User**

```
_id
Name
Photos: [...]
```

Once I have the database setup correctly, I can easily modify my code to use the new one, but the problem I'm having is figuring out how to quickly/procedural copy the documents to their parent.

Additional detail - I'm using MongoHQ.com to host my MongoDB.

Thank You.

Comment: You need to take care of any schema migrations like this yourself, in code.  Just update your `User` schema and then iterate over your collections to update your collections to reflect the new schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of your environment, but this sort of change usually involves the following kinds of steps:

1. Ensure that your old code doesn't complain if there is a `Photos` array in the User object.
2. "Freeze" the application so that new `User` and `Photo` documents are not created
3. Run a migration script that copies the `Photo` documents into the User `documents`. This should be pretty easy to create either in javaScript or through app code using the driver (see example below)
4. Deploy the new version of the application that expects `Photos` to be embedded in the array
5. "Unfreeze" the application to start creating new documents

If you cannot "Freeze/Unfreeze" you will need to run a delta script after step 4 that will migrate newly created `Photo` documents after the new application is deployed.

The script will look something like this (untested):

```
db.User.find().forEach(function (u) {
    u.Photos = new Array();
    db.Photo.find({user_id : u._id}).forEach(function (p) {
        u.Photos.push(p);
    }
    db.User.Save(u);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I thought it would be more complicated then that, but it definitely helps to have it explained.